# How to determine if the executing program was compiled for 64 bit?

Tags: c#, 64-bit

I need for my program to determine if it was compiled for 32 bit windows or 64 bit/any CPU. I need to choose a different COM server flag depending on the compilation options. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you more concerned with if it's currently running as a 32-bit or 64-bit application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Checking at run time if you are running a 64-bit application:**

To see whether your process is 64-bit or 32-bit you can simply check the **IntPtr.Size** or any other pointer type. If you get 4 then you are running on 32-bit. If you get 8 then you are running on 64-bit.

**What type of computer is your process running as:**

You can check the PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE environment variable to see if you are running on an x64, ia64 or x86 machine.

**Is your process running under emulation:**

The Win32 API IsWow64Process will tell you if you are running a 32-bit application under x64.  Wow64 means windows32 on windows64.

Contrary to what other people have posted: IsWow64Process will not tell you if you are running a 32-bit or a 64bit application.  On 32-bit machines it will tell you FALSE for 32-bit applications when run, and on a 64-bit machine it will tell you TRUE for a 32-bit application.   It only tells you if your application is running under emulation.

Comment: Hi Brian, _WIN64 seems to not be defined in vs2008. Any ideas?

Comment: I updated my answer, sorry at first I thought you said c++.   I updated it with C# information.

Answer (score 3):

Are you aware of [`Environment.Is64BitProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess.aspx)? 
It determines whether the current running process is a 64-bit process.

Answer (score 2):

You want the CORFLAGS command-line app from Microsoft. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699(VS.80).aspx

Comment: how corflags command line tool will help to identify an assembly is built for 32 bit/64 bit or *MSIL* ?

Comment: I found the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270531/how-to-determine-if-a-net-assembly-was-built-for-x86-or-x64. Thanks for your contribution @Walden Leverich

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [IsWow64Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139(VS.85).aspx) function to determine at runtime whethehr your COM server is a x64 or win32 process.

If you just want to know this during compile time: the compiler sets the _WIN64 macro.

Comment: From the docs: "If the application is a 64-bit application running under 64-bit Windows, the Wow64Process parameter is set to FALSE."... how does that help?

Comment: IsWow64Process will not tell you if you are running a 32-bit or a 64bit application.  On 32-bit machines it will tell you FALSE when run, and on a 64-bit machine it will tell you TRUE for a 32-bit application.

Comment: Hmmm, _WIN64 is apparently not working. The code is grayed out even though I'm compiling in 64 bit

Comment: _WIN64 is a c++ define, I don't think it gets defined for c#

Comment: _WIN64 gets defined by the compiler. But I thought you're using C++ not C# - my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

use GetBinaryType api function and you will have the type of the file

this is the link to the api on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364819(VS.85).aspx

the results are:

SCS_32BIT_BINARY = 32 bit exe

SCS_64BIT_BINARY = 64 bit exe

SCS_DOS_BINARY = DOS

SCS_OS216_BINARY = OS/2

SCS_WOW_BINARY = 16 bit

SCS_POSIX_BINARY = POSIX based

SCS_PIF_BINARY = PIF file that execute on DOS

Answer (score 1):

You could do this based on setting compile time constants and doing #ifs based on those to set a value that you can check to see which platform the application was compiled for. See [Target platform/processor at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524196/-net-target-platform-processor-at-compile-time).

The easiest other way is to check the IntPtr.Size property to see if it's 4 (32 bit), or 8 (64 bit).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [conditional methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288458(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

While it seems like an odd route to go, you can tell whether you're running in 32-bit (or 64-bit in WOW64) or 64-bit .NET code by checking IntPtr.Size.

On 32-bit/WOW64, IntPtr.Size is 4.

On 64-bit, IntPtr.Size is 8.

Source: [Migrating 32-bit Managed Code to 64-bit Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973190.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Predefined Macros to check compilation type

```
   #if (_WIN64) 
        const bool IS_64 = true;
    #else
       const bool IS_64 = false;
    #endif
```